# How do I set up a simple read time in python?

Tags: python

Write a Python program that reads in two times, an earlier time and a later time, and prints the difference between the two times in minutes as well as in hours/minutes. The format of the time is `HH:MMAM` or `H:MMAM` or `HH:MMPM or H:MMPM`. Also the `AM` or `PM` may be in lower case. A sample run of the program is shown below:
$ python3 Time.py

`Enter Earlier Time: 9:36aM`
`Enter Later   Time: 6:22PM`

Number of minutes between `9:36aM` and `6:22PM = 526`
The time difference between `9:36aM and`6:22PM = 8 hours and 46 minutes`.
The formatting of the output should be exactly as shown above. This program should be placed in a file called Time.py.

Comment: Have you seen the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module of the standard library? It can do exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is an example of datetime arithmetic in the datetime library.

---

You may want to review POSIX formating and standards, often dates are converted from
local to POSIX standards.

---

from
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

```
import time
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
today
atetime.date(2007, 12, 5)
today == date.fromtimestamp(time.time())
True
my_birthday = date(today.year, 6, 24)
if my_birthday < today:
my_birthday = my_birthday.replace(year=today.year + 1)
my_birthday
datetime.date(2008, 6, 24)
time_to_birthday = abs(my_birthday - today)
time_to_birthday.days
202
```